# Send a value to controller via a widget?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

I have a property model view. In this view, there's TbFileUpload widget to upload photos of the property. I'm trying to pass property_id from property view to photo/upload controller but got undefined property_id error.

Here's my property view:

```
<h1>View Property #<?php echo $model->id; ?></h1>

<!--content begins-->

<!--content ends-->

<div id="prop_description">
        <h5 id="prop_hd">Description</h5>
        <?php echo $model->description; ?>
</div>

<?php       
    echo $property_id= $model->id;
    $model_photo=new Photo;
    $model_photo->property_id = $property_id;
    ?>
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbFileUpload', array(
    'url' => $this->createUrl("photo/upload"),
    'model' => $model_photo,    
    'attribute' => 'picture', // see the attribute?
    'multiple' => true,
    'options' => array(
    'maxFileSize' => 2000000,
    'acceptFileTypes' => 'js:/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
))); ?>
```

the photo/upload controller

```
class PhotoController extends CController {
// ... more code here

/**
* Handles resource upload
* @throws CHttpException
*/


public function actionUpload()
{
    //Here we define the paths where the files will be stored temporarily
    $path = realpath( Yii::app( )->getBasePath( )."/../images/uploads/tmp/" )."/";
    $publicPath = Yii::app( )->getBaseUrl( )."/images/uploads/tmp/";

    header('Vary: Accept');
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && 
        (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json') !== false))
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
    } else {
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
    }
    $data = array();

    $model_photo = new Photo('upload');
    $model_photo->picture = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model_photo, 'picture');
    if ($model_photo->picture !== null  && $model_photo->validate(array('picture')))
    {
        // data from file                   
            $model_photo->type = $model_photo->picture->getType( );
            $model_photo->size = $model_photo->picture->getSize( );     
        //(optional) Generate a random name for our file
            $filename = md5( Yii::app( )->user->id.microtime( ).$model_photo->name);
            $filename .= ".".$model_photo->picture->getExtensionName( );

        $model_photo->picture->saveAs($path.$filename);
        $model_photo->name = $model_photo->picture->name;
///////////////////// i got the error here  ////////////////////////////////    
//$model_photo->property_id = $property_id;
        $model_photo->url = $publicPath.$filename;


        // save picture name
        if( $model_photo->save())
        {
            // return data to the fileuploader
            $data[] = array(

                //'property_id'=>$model_photo->picture->property_id,
                'name' => $model_photo->picture->name,
                'type' => $model_photo->picture->type,
                'size' => $model_photo->picture->size,
                // we need to return the place where our image has been saved
                'url' => $publicPath.$filename, // Should we add a helper method?
                // we need to provide a thumbnail url to display on the list
                // after upload. Again, the helper method now getting thumbnail.
                'thumbnail_url' =>  $publicPath."thumbs/$filename",
                // we need to include the action that is going to delete the picture
                // if we want to after loading 
                'delete_url' => $this->createUrl('photo/delete', 
                    array('id' => $model_photo->id, 'method' => 'uploader')),
                'delete_type' => 'POST');
        } else {
            $data[] = array('error' => 'Unable to save model after saving picture');
        }
    } else {
        if ($model_photo->hasErrors('picture'))
        {
            $data[] = array('error', $model_photo->getErrors('picture'));
        } else {
            throw new CHttpException(500, "Could not upload file ".     CHtml::errorSummary($model_photo));
        }
    }
    // JQuery File Upload expects JSON data
    echo json_encode($data);
} 
}
```

any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have that problem because you haven't passed `$property_id` to your `photo/upload`.

one way you could do this you can pass it via get variable. in your view:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbFileUpload', array(
    'url' => $this->createUrl("photo/upload", array( 'id='=> $model->id )),// I added to the uri
    'model' => $model_photo,    
    'attribute' => 'picture',
    'multiple' => true,
    'options' => array(
    'maxFileSize' => 2000000,
    'acceptFileTypes' => 'js:/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
)));
```

then in your `photo/controller` catch it:

```
$property_id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id' , null); // or simply: $property_id = $_GET['id'];
```

then use it however you need.

cheers

Comment: Thanks tinyByte! I tried your suggestion, but appending id to action URL gave me an error    
 
>>>404 Not Found
The system is unable to find the requested action "upload?id=21".

Comment: what your url looks like?

Comment: hi @tinyByte, http://localhost/realapp/index.php?r=property/view&id=21 is current view, the widget calls photo/upload controller with post value POST /realapp/index.php?r=photo/upload?id=21. 

I tried '/id=' instead of '?id=' no error but it did not work either

Comment: I pass the variable this way instead and it worked. Thanks @tinyByte   

 'url' => $this->createUrl("photo/upload",array('property_id'=>$property_id)),

Comment: yes that's another way but this url:`/realapp/index.php?r=photo/upload?id=21` is wrong because it has two `?`.a valid url has one `?` and the rest of parameters are seperated by `&`.so this is also valid:`/realapp/index.php?r=photo/upload&id=21`